# I keep getting undefined. Before the result shows

Tags: javascript

```js
let bigo = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

for(let i = bigo.length; i >= 0; i--){
  console.log(bigo[i]);
}
```

Result:

```
> undefined
> [ 7, 8, 9 ]
> [ 4, 5, 6 ]
> [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

I keep getting `undefined` before the result show. What am I doing wrong.

Comment: There is another problem, the index of the array in the computer starts from zero, so your i should be equal to bigo.length - 1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Loop through an array in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3010840/loop-through-an-array-in-javascript)

Comment: Probably a typo but you log `bigone` while your variable is `bigo`

Comment: @Ben It's not even the same language

Comment: @MariusROBERT Yeah, I know, I've retracted the flag

Answer (score 1):

The last index is `length - 1`, not `length`, which is why your first result will be out of bounds and show `undefined`.

Comment: You don't think this could be closed as a dupe?

Comment: @0stone0 this question has probably already been asked but you need to find it to close this one

Answer (score 0):

`bigo` is 3 items long but does not have anything at index position 3. This is because indices count from 0. You need to write `let i = bigo.length - 1`

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself the hassle and stop using index-based loops.

```js
let bigo = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

for (let arr of [...bigo].reverse()) {
  console.log(arr);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

If bigo.length = 9 the programm will ask for bigone[9], after that it will decrease i with 1. I think you messed up the order.

Comment: 1) ```bigo.length``` is 3, as it is a nested array. 2) Just stating "I think you messed up the order" is nowhere near specific enough for an answer. Be more specific and/or provide an alteration to the code that would solve the OPs issue.